Is it possible to change the color of an element when hovering the mouse cursor from html to Angular?
The button color is passed to the component as a string and it must be used in the button styles. I managed to adjust the background-color and border, but I can't change the color of the label when hovering over it. I found a partial solution, but it also changes other buttons:
@for (button of toast.buttons; track button){
        <button
          [ngStyle]="hovered === 1 ? {'background-color': button.color, 'border-color':button.color, 'color':button.color} : {'background-color': button.color, 'border-color':button.color, 'color':'#fff'}"
          (mouseover)="hovered = 1"
          (mouseout)="hovered = -1"
          (click)="close()"
          class="modal-button">
          {{button.text}}
        </button>
      }

Here I tried to change the color of the text on hover using mouseover and mouseout, but this led to the following result:
Without hover:

With hover:

As you can see, when you hover over one button, the second one is also colored.
I tried to look for solutions on the Internet, but I didn't find anything intelligible.
Can you tell me if there is a way to avoid such a result? For example, passing the value of the button.color variable to a css file or otherwise handling the hover.

why not simply make use of the :hover selector at CSS level?

You can achieve this with pure CSS and :hover. You can use CSS variables for injecting the color into CSS.
.modal-button {
  background-color: var(--modal-button-color);
  border-color: var(--modal-button-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  color: var(--modal-button-color);
}

Template:
@for (button of toast.buttons; track button){
  <button
    [style.--modal-button-color]="button.color"
    (click)="close()"
    class="modal-button">
    {{button.text}}
  </button>
}


Thanks! This method helped me solve my problem.
